# What's correct here?

Tags: grammar

1) "Today the number of referrals passed are 24"

2) "Today the number of 
referrals passed is 24"

Please help. Using 'IS' or 'ARE' which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case 'IS' is the correct form as 'number' is a singular noun not plural.